# Newbie looking for simple example of connecting to SQL using asp.net MVC with VB.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

So I am looking to freshen up my dev skills.   I come from a classic ASP background using VB, so this new .net and Model concept is very foreign to me.   I cant seem to get my head wrapped around it yet.   I have tried going through the tutorials, but most are C# and I plan to use VB.net.

My needs at the moment are very simple (or at least i thought they were)  Does anyone have a simple example or explanation of how I can create a simple page that pulls data from a local SQL Express DB?

I understand how the Controllers and Views work(mostly), but the Models just make zero sense to me

I created a new Model for a very simple database called Test.   It has only 5 columns. (Username, Password, Email_Address, Text_number, and UserID (UID).  It created a Model1.edmx, but that's it.  Nothing else below it.   Where the heck do I go from here?

Uggghhh I feel so dumb!!   I used to be OK at this, now it's SOOO different!!  I miss my T-SQL, Recordsets, and Loops.

Comment: I suggest looking for a tutorial.  I found one from Microsoft with C# when I wanted to look at MVC.  Dollars to donuts they have one for vb as well.

Comment: Yeah I found them but they were all code first, not db first.   I like to setup the db first (that or I am pulling from an existing DB).   I cant seem to find any that show DB first using vb.net.  Is it really that lengthy in ASP.net MVC4 to pull data from an existing SQL db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want db first you should create a new .edmx Model using "generate from database".

When you have created an .edmx model then you usually create your Entity Classes (see tutorials below) with the "add code generation item". You can read about this in one of the linked tutorials, under "Generating Strongly Typed Entity Classes". After that you're ready to go the controller and create your first query to return some data.

I suggest you start watching these free tutorials about MVC3/4, even if they are in C# and you want to use vb.net, I'm sure you can easily understand what's going on since it's clearly explained

1. http://www.asp.net/mvc/pluralsight

also read these tutorials that show database first approaches

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj206878
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489.aspx  - VB.net project

Answer (score 0):

To connect to your database, you might want to consider an ORM, like one of the following:

- Entity Framework
- NHibernate
- Linq2Sql  (built-in/already installed)

Each of these are very popular and make it easy to quickly snap a code-wrapper around your DB.  Then, in your model, you use the ORM objects(wrapping your DB) to call through to the DB.

Comment: Thanks guys.  You're awesome.  Between the two answers I was able to finally build a model that pulled the SQL data and created my crud!  I won't lie, I was pretty ecstatic! :-) this is my first time using stack overflow and you guys came through.